# Maximum call stack size exceeded in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Everyone!

I tried to make the recursion in order to expand my $routeProvider in Angular.js this is the code I tried to implement:

```
var pages = {
'home': {
    'url': '/',
    'partialName': 'index',
    'link': partialDir + this.partialName + pageFormat,
    'controllerName': this.partialName + 'Controller',
    'pageTitle': 'Welcome home'
},
'page': {
    'url': '/page',
    'partialName': 'page',
    'link': partialDir + this.partialName + pageFormat,
    'controllerName': this.partialName + 'Controller',
    'pageTitle': 'Page'
},
'page2': {
    'url': '/page2',
    'partialName': 'page2',
    'link': partialDir + this.partialName + pageFormat,
    'controllerName': this.partialName + 'Controller',
    'pageTitle': 'Page2'
}

angular.forEach(pages, function(value, key) {
    console.log(value);

    $routeProvider.when(value.url,{
        templateUrl: value.link
    })
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

and I get

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

How can I solve this problem?

Uncaught exception(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12450ident.$get @ angular.js:9237invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8782nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546$route.link @ angular-route.js:985invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7546name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7690controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8307update @ angular-route.js:935$animate.link @ angular-route.js:900invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8780nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8280compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7671
6angular.js:12450 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function (native)
    at Object.ASTCompiler.compile

Comment: What does your call stack look like when the error is thrown?

Comment: What does `pages` look like?

Comment: @charliefl I have updated the question.

Comment: The object initialization you're attempting won't work. You can't use `this` in an object initializer to reference other parts of the object being created; that's not how object initializers work.

Comment: How many `ng-view`s do you have? Make sure the template you're loading into an `ng-view` doesn't have any further `ng-view`s defined.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the call stack you provided, it looks like one or more of your page templates includes an `ng-view` directive. ngRoute only allows one `ng-view` to be defined in your main layout page.

Comment: I've checked twice. There is only one  `ng-view` directive.